# Quarkus Unsatisfied dependency for type. Using Extension

Tags: java, dependency-injection, quarkus

I have next structure:

1. Quarkus extension 'core' with interface *SomeInterface* and bean *SomeContainer*:

   ```
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class SomeContainer {

      @Inject
      SomeInterface someInterface;
    }
   ```
2. Quarkus extension 'implementation' with *SomeImpl* bean:

   ```
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class SomeImpl implements SomeInterface {

    }
   ```
3. Quarkus application - 'starter' which depend quarkus extension 'implementation' and jax rs controller:

   ```
    @Path("/hello")
    public class GreetingResource {

      @Inject
      SomeContainer someContainer;

      @GET
      @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String hello() {

      }
   }
   ```

When I try start app I get an error:

```
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unsatisfied dependency for type by.test.core.SomeInterface and qualifiers [@Default]
```

How to fix it?
link to project https://github.com/flagmen/quarkus-test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *starter* module only depends on the *core* module which by itself does not contain a CDI injectable candidate for the `SomeInterface`.

You should add the *implementation* module holding the discoverable bean as a dependency as well:

```
<!-- quarkus-test/starter/pom.xml -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>by.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>by.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>implementation</artifactId> <!-- you can even omit the core module as it will be transitively imported -->
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```